# How to add tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty in Miktex?

Tags: miktex

I am trying to install ms package so that I can solve the problem but after unzipping the zip file, I found no application file to install ms package. Because of this I can't install ms package. Please kindly help me about this matter.

Comment: Why are you installing this by hand when miktex comes with a package manager that does it for you? And the ms package **is** available in MikTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...This is one of an in-built package which comes along with all types of `LaTeX` distributions, hence please check your `setup` if it was not available...

Comment: Thank you so much